# Shared Element Transitions in Vue : how to transition between related elements in distinct views on route change

Tags: vue.js, transition, vue-router, shared-element-transition, vuepress

How to transition between two elements defined in two distinct views on route change, often called "*Shared transitions*" or "*Native-like transitions*" of pages elements across multiple pages layouts ?

Here are some examples :

- [Shared Element Transitions](https://github.com/airbnb/native-navigation/blob/master/docs/guides/shared-element-transitions.md) in [airbnb/native-navigation](https://github.com/airbnb/native-navigation) (React)
- [Animation Anchoring](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#animation-anchoring-via-ng-animate-ref-) (Angular)

Common solutions are faking this effect by using distinct elements outside the pages flow or by overlaying the elements across layouts and using voluntary voids and absolute positioning that take into account the overlays spaces to give the impression that the element is built into the natural page flow. See for example [Native-Like Animations for Page Transitions on the Web](https://css-tricks.com/native-like-animations-for-page-transitions-on-the-web/) (see [comment](https://css-tricks.com/native-like-animations-for-page-transitions-on-the-web/#comment-1625522)) or [snipcart/vue-blog-demo](http://github.com/snipcart/vue-blog-demo).

A *Shared Element Transition* would create a relation between two elements defined separately in distinct views with different pages layouts, and would transition between them, probably in a kind of FLIP way.

Comment: This is exactly what you want: https://github.com/snipcart/vue-blog-demo

Comment: @JoseFG It seems to me that there is no "targeted" transition : the animated elements are defined once outside the BlogPost layout, by using the (filtered) posts list as hero image (https://github.com/snipcart/vue-blog-demo/blob/master/src/components/BlogFeed.vue) The image is thus not defined in the post layout https://github.com/snipcart/vue-blog-demo/blob/master/src/components/BlogPost.vue, and the final layout has to be constructed without embedding the hero image, by using absolute or fixed positions to take the image space into account.

Comment: @JoseFG I edited the question with more precisions about that.

Answer (score 4):

The library [vue-overdrive](https://github.com/mattrothenberg/vue-overdrive) simulate such transition between distinct components by using [Ramjet](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/ramjet).

> [Ramjet](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/ramjet) makes it look like your DOM elements are capable of transforming into one another. It does this by cloning the elements (and all their children), transforming the second element (the one we're transforming to) so that it completely overlaps with the first, then animating the two elements together until the first element (the one we're transitioning from) has exactly the same position and dimensions as the second element originally did.